# Title in plot_grid in rstudio

Tags: rstudio

I am using the following code to set up 9 plots in one figure, and to save it

```
plotpm2.5 <- plot_grid(p1,p2,p3,p4,p5,p6,p7,p8,p9, ncol = 3, nrow = 3, align 
= "h")
save_plot("plotpm2.5.png", plotpm2.5,
      ncol = 3,
      nrow = 3,
      base_aspect_ratio = 1.5)
```

how can I add a main title to this?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not too sure about is but here us something that might help. For example:

```
    title <- ggdraw() + draw_label("label", fontface='bold')             
            plot_grid(title, x, ncol=1, rel_heights=c(0.1, 1))
```

rel_heights controls the margin values for the title. Play with the arguments inside plot_grid to finally get a title that suits you.